# Add access token to FB.Data.query() call

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am able to run some FQL statements without problems as long as it doesn't require an access code.

I would like to run the following FQL, but according to the documentation it requires at least a generic access code.

```
var query = FB.Data.query('SELECT eid, uid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 104821622923594');
```

I am able to successfully create an access token using php and access that page by navigating to it in the browser:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/104821622923594/events?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I was hoping to actually use the Javascript SDK, so how do I add the access token I generate to this FB.Data.query request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use FB.api instead:

```
FB.api(
{
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=me()',
    access_token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
},
function(response) {
    alert('Your name is ' + response[0].name);
}
);
```

details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/